# Postgresql generate UTC timestamp without daylight savings

Tags: javascript, postgresql, timezone, pg-promise

I'm trying to generate a simple time series with postgresql like this:

```
[
  { date_trunc: 2007-02-01T00:00:00.000Z },
  { date_trunc: 2007-02-02T00:00:00.000Z },
  { date_trunc: 2007-02-03T00:00:00.000Z },
  { date_trunc: 2007-02-04T00:00:00.000Z },
  { date_trunc: 2007-02-05T00:00:00.000Z },
  { date_trunc: 2007-02-06T00:00:00.000Z },
  { date_trunc: 2007-02-07T00:00:00.000Z },
  { date_trunc: 2007-02-08T00:00:00.000Z },
  ...
]
```

For this I use this piece of code (using timestampz to avoid messy time zones):

```
    SELECT date_trunc('day', dd):: timestamptz
    FROM generate_series
            ( '2007-02-01'::timestamptz
            , '2008-02-01'::timestamptz 
            , '1 day'::interval) dd
            ;
```

yet it generates this result:

```
[
  { date_trunc: 2007-01-31T23:00:00.000Z },
  { date_trunc: 2007-02-01T23:00:00.000Z },
  { date_trunc: 2007-02-02T23:00:00.000Z },
  { date_trunc: 2007-02-03T23:00:00.000Z },
  { date_trunc: 2007-02-04T23:00:00.000Z },
  { date_trunc: 2007-02-05T23:00:00.000Z },
  { date_trunc: 2007-02-06T23:00:00.000Z },
  { date_trunc: 2007-02-07T23:00:00.000Z },
  { date_trunc: 2007-02-08T23:00:00.000Z },
  { date_trunc: 2007-02-09T23:00:00.000Z },
  { date_trunc: 2007-02-10T23:00:00.000Z },
  { date_trunc: 2007-02-11T23:00:00.000Z },
  { date_trunc: 2007-02-12T23:00:00.000Z },
  { date_trunc: 2007-02-13T23:00:00.000Z },
  { date_trunc: 2007-02-14T23:00:00.000Z },
  { date_trunc: 2007-02-15T23:00:00.000Z },
  { date_trunc: 2007-02-16T23:00:00.000Z },
  { date_trunc: 2007-02-17T23:00:00.000Z },
  { date_trunc: 2007-02-18T23:00:00.000Z },
  { date_trunc: 2007-02-19T23:00:00.000Z },
  { date_trunc: 2007-02-20T23:00:00.000Z },
  { date_trunc: 2007-02-21T23:00:00.000Z },
  { date_trunc: 2007-02-22T23:00:00.000Z },
  { date_trunc: 2007-02-23T23:00:00.000Z },
  { date_trunc: 2007-02-24T23:00:00.000Z },
  { date_trunc: 2007-02-25T23:00:00.000Z },
  { date_trunc: 2007-02-26T23:00:00.000Z },
  { date_trunc: 2007-02-27T23:00:00.000Z },
  { date_trunc: 2007-02-28T23:00:00.000Z },
  { date_trunc: 2007-03-01T23:00:00.000Z },
  { date_trunc: 2007-03-02T23:00:00.000Z },
  { date_trunc: 2007-03-03T23:00:00.000Z },
  { date_trunc: 2007-03-04T23:00:00.000Z },
  { date_trunc: 2007-03-05T23:00:00.000Z },
  { date_trunc: 2007-03-06T23:00:00.000Z },
  { date_trunc: 2007-03-07T23:00:00.000Z },
  { date_trunc: 2007-03-08T23:00:00.000Z },
  { date_trunc: 2007-03-09T23:00:00.000Z },
  { date_trunc: 2007-03-10T23:00:00.000Z },
  { date_trunc: 2007-03-11T23:00:00.000Z },
  { date_trunc: 2007-03-12T23:00:00.000Z },
  { date_trunc: 2007-03-13T23:00:00.000Z },
  { date_trunc: 2007-03-14T23:00:00.000Z },
  { date_trunc: 2007-03-15T23:00:00.000Z },
  { date_trunc: 2007-03-16T23:00:00.000Z },
  { date_trunc: 2007-03-17T23:00:00.000Z },
  { date_trunc: 2007-03-18T23:00:00.000Z },
  { date_trunc: 2007-03-19T23:00:00.000Z },
  { date_trunc: 2007-03-20T23:00:00.000Z },
  { date_trunc: 2007-03-21T23:00:00.000Z },
  { date_trunc: 2007-03-22T23:00:00.000Z },
  { date_trunc: 2007-03-23T23:00:00.000Z },
  { date_trunc: 2007-03-24T23:00:00.000Z },
  { date_trunc: 2007-03-25T22:00:00.000Z },
  { date_trunc: 2007-03-26T22:00:00.000Z },
  { date_trunc: 2007-03-27T22:00:00.000Z },
  { date_trunc: 2007-03-28T22:00:00.000Z },
  { date_trunc: 2007-03-29T22:00:00.000Z },
  { date_trunc: 2007-03-30T22:00:00.000Z },
  { date_trunc: 2007-03-31T22:00:00.000Z },
  { date_trunc: 2007-04-01T22:00:00.000Z },
  { date_trunc: 2007-04-02T22:00:00.000Z },
  { date_trunc: 2007-04-03T22:00:00.000Z },
  { date_trunc: 2007-04-04T22:00:00.000Z },
  { date_trunc: 2007-04-05T22:00:00.000Z },
  { date_trunc: 2007-04-06T22:00:00.000Z },
  { date_trunc: 2007-04-07T22:00:00.000Z },
  { date_trunc: 2007-04-08T22:00:00.000Z },
  { date_trunc: 2007-04-09T22:00:00.000Z },
  { date_trunc: 2007-04-10T22:00:00.000Z },
  { date_trunc: 2007-04-11T22:00:00.000Z },
  { date_trunc: 2007-04-12T22:00:00.000Z },
  { date_trunc: 2007-04-13T22:00:00.000Z },
  { date_trunc: 2007-04-14T22:00:00.000Z },
  { date_trunc: 2007-04-15T22:00:00.000Z },
  { date_trunc: 2007-04-16T22:00:00.000Z },
  { date_trunc: 2007-04-17T22:00:00.000Z },
  { date_trunc: 2007-04-18T22:00:00.000Z },
  { date_trunc: 2007-04-19T22:00:00.000Z },
  { date_trunc: 2007-04-20T22:00:00.000Z },
  { date_trunc: 2007-04-21T22:00:00.000Z },
  { date_trunc: 2007-04-22T22:00:00.000Z },
  { date_trunc: 2007-04-23T22:00:00.000Z },
  { date_trunc: 2007-04-24T22:00:00.000Z },
  { date_trunc: 2007-04-25T22:00:00.000Z },
  { date_trunc: 2007-04-26T22:00:00.000Z },
  { date_trunc: 2007-04-27T22:00:00.000Z },
  { date_trunc: 2007-04-28T22:00:00.000Z },
  { date_trunc: 2007-04-29T22:00:00.000Z },
  { date_trunc: 2007-04-30T22:00:00.000Z },
  { date_trunc: 2007-05-01T22:00:00.000Z },
  { date_trunc: 2007-05-02T22:00:00.000Z },
  { date_trunc: 2007-05-03T22:00:00.000Z },
  { date_trunc: 2007-05-04T22:00:00.000Z },
  { date_trunc: 2007-05-05T22:00:00.000Z },
  { date_trunc: 2007-05-06T22:00:00.000Z },
  { date_trunc: 2007-05-07T22:00:00.000Z },
  { date_trunc: 2007-05-08T22:00:00.000Z },
  { date_trunc: 2007-05-09T22:00:00.000Z },
  { date_trunc: 2007-05-10T22:00:00.000Z },
  ... 266 more items
]
```

As you can see it is one year behind and at 25. March it switches time zones anyway. So how can I avoid this and simply use regular UTC timestamps without 1 hour delay aswell as daylight savings?

I just realized this also doesn't work:

```
SELECT '2007-3-1'::timestamptz

=>
{ date: 2007-02-28T23:00:00.000Z }
```

So I'm not sure if I understand what timestamptz even does

Comment: Why don't you just use `timestamp` instead?

Comment: Same result no change

Comment: Works for me: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=e9d147860f993397cc38427bbdc537c7 - but if you don't need a time part anyway, why not just use `date` then?

Comment: same result for me even if I use timestamp or date. You are probably in the uk and thats why it works for you. I suspect it saves it correctly but displays it wrong

Comment: No, I am not in the UK. I guess that your SQL tool (or application framework) messes with those values. A `DATE` value cannot possible show this behaviour

Comment: hmm i didnt even think about that. It works when I do it in psql, so I guess the  culprit is pg-promise. Thanks  a lot

Comment: @user2741831 What you're seeing then is the normal behavior of JavaScript `Date` objects - pg-promise did parse the date representation using your system timezone. You can prevent that by casting to `::text` in your query.

Comment: @user2741831 However, `timestamptz` usually works correct - it's just interpreted as an absolute point in time, and creates the correct `Date` object to represent that instant. The date object may by default be shown in your system timezone (though then you should see `2007-05-04T22:00:00.000T+02:00` for UTC midnight!), but you can also display it in UTC by using `.toISOString()` or the `.getUTC…()` methods.